# Laptop memory upgrade confusion

Tags: laptop, memory

I am planning to order a Lenovo ThinkPad E570. It comes with a 4GB DDR4 SODIMM stick. I want to throw in more RAM. So

1) if it's a DDR4 system, would it support DDR3 as well?

2) should I buy an 8GB DDR4 (4+8 =12GB) stick or just get 2 8GB DDR (16GB) sticks for the same price ?

3) how would going for a DDR3 impact performance and also battery life?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) if it's a DDR4 system, would it support DDR3 as well?

Generally speaking, NO. What's the manual say?

> 2) should I buy an 8GB DDR4 (4+8 =12GB) stick or just get 2 8GB DDR (16GB) sticks for the same price ?

What's the documentation say about it?  If 16 GB is supported, it is what I would do, provided it is DDR4.  Otherwise just go with adding the 8 GB stick.

> 3) how would going for a DDR3 impact performance and also battery life?

It probably won't work, so performance will be severely impacted.

Comment: Clear and savage answer

Comment: I wasn't trying to be savage, but it is a rather blunt answer.